# When is being flat a derived invariant?

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories

For which commutative rings k is the following true:

> A k-algebra $A$ that is flat over $k$ and derived equivalent to a $k$-algebra $B$ implies that also $B$ is flat over $k$.

The motivation is this: Many results on derived equivalences start with two k-algebras A and B that are assumed to be flat and derived equivalent. Maybe it is often enough to just assume one is flat?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but one necessary condition, which rules out many popular commutative rings, is that $k$ should have no finitely generated module $M$ with flat dimension equal to one.